# Cloth Simulator Acting Strange

Tags: cloth-simulation

This flag seems to be pulling into itself for some reason. I've been successful in creating a flag along with wind physics before, but that was with only the flag in the project.

Now, following the same steps I had done before, the below is the result when I play the animation. The only difference is that there are quite a few objects in this scene. For one, the rocks are part of a particle system.

My guess is that the flag is influenced by something else in the scene, maybe?

[image]
[image]

Comment: is your flag a plane? that means no solidify. Try turning off self collision and see if it acts up